# Triggers: how can I initialize the value on a table with a value on another?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, sql

I'm creating a trigger to initialize the value plazas_disponibles on table VUELO with the value capacidad on table MODELO. Like this:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER inicializar_plazas_disponibles
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON VUELO 
    BEGIN
         SET VUELO (plazas_disponibles) = MODELO (capacidad);
    END inicializar_plazas_disponibles;
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error(2,10): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(2,14): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Error(2,23): PL/SQL: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
```

Why?

Comment: What are the schema for `VUELO` and `MODELO`? What's the relationship between rows in the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Because that isn't how you change a value in the row being inserted - you need to modify it using the `:NEW` syntax ([documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm)); and you haven't shown how to retrieve a relevant value from the `MODELO` table.

You need to do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER inicializar_plazas_disponibles
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON vuelo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT capacidad
    INTO :NEW.plazas_disponibles
    FROM modelo
    WHERE ... some condition, presumably another :NEW column ...
END;
```

<strike>(Although I'm not entirely sure whether you can select straight into a `:NEW` value - try that, but if not you'll need to declare a variable of the same type, select into that instead, and then assign that to the `:NEW`).</strike>